# Log the error generated in Subscribe and Preview of a Test send

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a method to log the errors that Salesforce marketing cloud displays while doing a Subscribe and Preview in a Test send?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to hit a journey via POSTMAN. Even if there is some error in the email, the POSTMAN shows me status 201, ie., success. But obviously i dont get the email. So i need to catch the errors SFMC generated while doing a Test send.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to store the logs when you preview an email. Yet, what you can do is:

1- When an email is failed while sending, you can ask Salesforce Support to get the logs for this particular email. You can also do that on your end - again after you send the emails as a test or actual sendout - with the use of RaiseError but you need to specify your errors: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/raiseerror.htm

2- You can check and log the problems manually by creating a Cloudpage and following this way: [Error Handing in Ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175549/error-handing-in-ampscript)

Comment: Thanks mate. But i have already used this approach to handle known errors. I need to handle the unknowns errors that i get while hitting the journey through POSTMAN.