# Delete individual record from Data Extension through cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

[image: I want to delete particular record as shown in image]Very pleasure for the solution.
Want to delete individual/particular records from landing page, but unable to delete.

```
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="POST">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1px">
           <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>ExternalKey</td>
                        <td>EmailAddress</td>
                        <td>ThresholdCount</td>
             <td>ScheduledFrequency</td>
                      </tr>
%%[

var @EmailName, @ExternalKey, @EmailAddress, @PrimaryKey, @SetCount, @ScheduledFrequency, @row, @rows, @URL, @rowCount, @i, @ipkvalue, @pkvalue

set @Flag = "True"
set @rows = LookupRows("CloudEmailNotificationDE","Flag",@Flag)

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
set @EmailName = field(@row,"EmailName")
set @ExternalKey = field(@row,"ExternalKey")
set @EmailAddress = field(@row,"EmailAddress")
set @SetCount = field(@row,"SetCount")
set @ScheduledFrequency = field(@row,"ScheduledFrequency")
set @PrimaryKey = field(@row,"PrimaryKey")
set @ipkvalue = concat("PrimaryKey",@i)
set @pkvalue = Requestparameter(@ipkvalue)
set @URL = concat('https://pub.s10.exacttarget.com/2g0j2bq1lq0')

if RequestParameter("deleted") == "deleted" then

set @deleteCount = DeleteData("CloudEmailNotificationDE",'ExternalKey',@ExternalKey,'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'ScheduledFrequency',@ScheduledFrequency)
Redirect(@URL)
endif

]%%


          <tr>
                        <td>%%=v(@EmailName)=%%</td>
                        <td>%%=v(@ExternalKey)=%%</td>
                        <td>%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%</td>
                        <td>%%=v(@SetCount)=%%</td>
             <td>%%=v(@ScheduledFrequency)=%%</td>
            <td><input id="PrimaryKey" type="hidden" name="%%=v(@deleteCount)=%%" value="%%=v(@deleteCount)=%%"></td>
            <td><input id="deleted" type="hidden" name="deleted" value="deleted"></td>
            <td align="left">&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
            
                      </tr>
        
%%[ next @i ]%%%%[ else ]%%%%[ endif ]%%
         
          </table>
  
        </form>
         deleteCount: %%=v(@deleteCount)=%%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: And what is your question? Do you get an error message? Is the record not deleted?

Comment: @LukasLunow  thanks for the reply, unable to delete the record individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting anything that would let the script know which row to delete.
Also, please include the output you are getting with your code in your question.

Comment: Thanks @DonL for the reply,
1. We are not getting any output and page redirecting to the same page where we submit.

Comment: if you are not getting any output, please wrap your code with a ssjs try catch block (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175549/error-handing-in-ampscript)

Also if you are redirecting to a cloudpage use the CloudPagesURL function.

Comment: Thanks @DonL for the reply,
1. We are not getting any output and page redirecting to the same page where we submit.
2. I am confused to write script that let to delete the row. Because i want to delete each row separately by giving button.